# How to turn OFF Alt-Key shortcuts in WPF

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5

[.Net 3.5] I have a WPF UserControl called PickList.

Picklist has a Grid with a UserControl called TouchGrid, and a DependencyProperty called BoundFieldProperty, which is a string.

TouchGrid has an ObservableCollection property called Columns.

TouchGridColumn is a UIElement.

Finally, I have some XAML that defines a PickList called imageList.  It defines BoundField as "Name".

I don't know if this will be enough to work with; I wouldn't ask you to wade through all these user-defined controls.

The way I use this is to assign imageList's DataSource to a list of objects that have a "Name" property, so my PickList then becomes a list of strings.  The problem is that if a string has one or more underscores in it, the first one is considered an alt-key shortcut, so it "disappears" from the display unless I hit my Alt key.  [For the record, this is a touch-screen app!]

I guess this must be some kind of default at the UIElement level, although nothing jumps out at me; Can anyone guess where I might go to defeat this?

Comment: One does wonder why you have strings with underscores that you are displaying to an end user. The underscore character is not a glyph in any natural language I have ever seen. We as programmers sometimes forget this.

Comment: The data is user-defined, it is what it is; the programmer just has to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Microsoft MVP said this feature is not optional in WPF.  The preferred solution is to double the underscores.  I added a read-only DisplayName property to the type in my list and made that the BoundField, which had been Name.  DisplayName "get" looks like this:

```
return new Regex( "_" ).Replace( Name, "__" );
```

I won't always be able to change the underlying object, however, so in another place, I got the same results by setting up the DataSource like this:

```
imageList.DataSource = WorkOrderImages.Select( w => new
{
    w,
    DisplayName = ( new Regex( "_" ).Replace( w.Name, "__" ) )
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a DataTemplate for the items that contains a TextBlock which would bind to the name property. The TextBlock control doesn't respect the Alt-Key shortcut identifies and should display your text the way it is stored.